# Problems while installing Nvidia-367 Driver on Ubuntu-16.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I had earlier installed nvidia-340, using

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

I was trying to install Cuda-8, but it required nvidia-367. So I removed nvidia-340 and all other nvidia products, using

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia
```

Then installed nvidia 367, using

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
```

Now though nvidia-prime shows version as 367, in additional drivers section, nouveau is selected and the other option is nvidia-340 (unselected). There is no option for nvidia-367.

And when I switched to nvidia-340 in additional drivers section, nvidia-prime started showing version as 340.

So my problem is that I'm unable to install nvidia-367 successfully on my computer. Output of dpkg is:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  bbswitch-dkms                                 0.8-3ubuntu1                                                amd64        Interface for toggling the power on NVIDIA Optimus video cards
ii  libcuda1-340                                  340.101-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                    amd64        NVIDIA CUDA runtime library
ii  nvidia-340                                    340.101-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                    amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.101
rc  nvidia-367                                    367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1+gpu16.04.1                          amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-340                         340.101-0ubuntu0.16.04.1                                    amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                         367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1+gpu16.04.1                          amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.2                                                       amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               375.26-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                                  amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Note that both nvidia-340 and nvidia-367 come in the list.

The interesting thing is when I remove all nvidia drivers; even though "dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia" shows nothing, nvidia-340 still appears in additional drivers section.

PS: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a notebook PC, GPU is Nvidia GeForce 820M.

Comment: Ok I think I solved it. Actually the additional drivers section is faulty, and even when I have nvidia-367 installed, it show nouveau as selected.

Comment: Neat! You should try answering your own question show that it shows up for other users :)